# Efficient methods of Chaining Uninterruptible Power Supplies

Tags: power-supply, batteries, ups

Let's assume I have 2 identical UPS and deep cycles are not preferred for battery lifetime.

I can think of 3 different methods to combine. Which one of these methods should I be using under which circumstance? Or should I even use these methods?

- Daisy Chaining. I plug them in series. Straight forward but the first one closer to the grid will die very quickly.
- Taking out the batteries from the first UPS and Connecting them up to the other battery pack in parallel. Current limit in total will be reduced but at least will I have twice the Ah storage?
- Paralleling UPS outputs. Can this be achieved ?

Comment: Some high end UPSes can do the third option. Do you only need the power from one of then but the energy from two? Option number two looks the easiest then.

Comment: Both have 2kWatt max current limit. I want 4kWatt limit if possible. Or i will just use 2nd method but still i can't draw more than 2kW. Now i'm using 1st method and it hurts during outage.

Comment: @winny i dont think they are high end. I bought them from pc store, generic commercial UPSes.

Comment: IF they are cheap, just combine the batteries... 4kW is a fairly large PSU, in that case you could also build your own to some extent, a cheap trickle charger, and a cheap 4kW Car inverter...

Comment: Heath Robinson method could use changeover relays. With "due care" you may be able to manage the changeover from A to A+B to B in some manner BUT they are liable to be (read will be) non synchronised so avoiding dropout is an issue.

Comment: I never said yours are high end. I said some high end. Combining to 4 kW without the inbuilt option/feature from the manufacturer is near impossible. Settle with 2 kW and twice the capacity or get another UPS.

Comment: @winny i have dozens dude i want to install them on house :D thats why im asking.

Comment: Is this for some sort of PV system? I have something like that on my house with two different UPS´s that I picked up cheap. What I have done is simply split the house supply to suit the UPS (one is 1200VA, the other 2200VA).

Comment: @F.Bloggs I'm not familiar with PV i see it is about solar energy. During power outage generator kicks in about 7-10 seconds. I have access to old UPSes. Can i somehow install these to my house so i wont even realize the power shortage. I know that momentary avg. usage is 2.5-3kWatt . and when i turn on cooking gear and washing machine peak is about 5kWatt. Can i just use lots of UPS in parralell to power high current system   for 30-60 seconds ?

Comment: I see that if i try to use second method i see that i can power my pc and some lights for hours But i need to hook them up in parallel in order to use this for high current but short term.